# Compile only one Storyboard file?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

We decided we needed to redesign our UI so we created a new storyboard but when building the project it compiles the new storyboard, **and** the old storyboard. Both of these files are very large so they both take ~10 seconds each to compile. Obviously this is an annoyance, is there anyway to mark the other one so it doesn't compile **without** deleting it?

Comment: You can delete it from the project file but can keep it in your project internal folder.

Comment: Go to the target's Build Phases settings. Remove all the files you don't want from Copy Bundle Resources. Alternatively open the storyboard files you don't want and have all the Target Membership boxes unchecked.

Comment: Thanks Sikhapol! Building is no longer a pain!